# Circle Circumscribed About Acute Triangle

Tags: geometry

The circle circumscribed about acute triangle $T$ has area $\pi$.

If the length of the longest side of triangle $T$ is $x$, what is the least possible value of $x?$

Comment: Welcome to our site! Here's a great tutorial to make your questions and answers look well polished: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:   any triangle has (at least) one angle $\alpha \ge 60^\circ\,$, otherwise the $3$ angles could not add up to $180^\circ\,$. By the [law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines), the side opposite that angle will be $a = 2R \sin \alpha\,$. Since the triangle is an acute one and $\sin x$ is increasing on $[0,90^\circ]\,$, it follows that $a = 2R \sin \alpha \ge 2 R \sin 60^\circ = \sqrt{3}R\,$. Therefore, the longest side of any acute triangle inscribed in a circle of radius $R$ is at least $\sqrt{3} R\,$, and that's the best lower bound since equality is attained for the equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

A circle with area $\pi$ means it has a radius of $1.$ To obtain the lowest possible length of $x$, we would need the triangle not only to be acute, but equilateral as well.

There is also a formula that links these two together, I was not aware of this before looking into this problem, which works only for equilateral triangles:
$$x = \sqrt{3} r$$

Comment: Whoops initially read that as max not min. Will try to change

Comment: Should be better now, anyone with more knowledge feel free to provide more